# Invalid update expression exception in EntityFramework Extensions UpdateFromQuery

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm using EF 6 and Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.

The following code:

```
using (var context = contextFactory())
{
    var modified = context.Receita.
        Where(r => r.V_UID == receitaEletronica.VendaUid && r.numeroreceita == receitaEletronica.NumeroReceita).
        Join(context.Tabela_Comparticipacao.
            Where(t => entidades.Contains(t.ec_uid)).
            Join(context.Tabela_Comparticipacao.Where(t => t.flag_elect == 1),
                source => source.ec_uid,
                dest => dest.ec_uid,
                (source, dest) => new { Source = source, Dest = dest }),
            r => r.TaCo_UID,
            t => t.Source.TaCo_UID,
            (r, t) => new { Receita = r, NovoTaCo = t.Dest.TaCo_UID }).
        UpdateFromQuery(r => new Receita { TaCo_UID = r.NovoTaCo });
}
```

throws the following exception:

```
Message: 
    Test method winphar.services.receitas.ReceitasDAOTest.TestAtualizarReceitaElectronicaTaCoUidEntidadesCentralizadas threw exception: 
    System.Exception: Oops! Invalid update expression, the body is not a NewExpression. Please refer to the documentation to get examples about how to use this feature.
  Stack Trace: 
    DbContextExtensions.[](IQueryable`1 , Expression`1 , Action`1 , Boolean )
    DbContextExtensions.UpdateFromQuery[TEntity](IQueryable`1 query, Expression`1 updateExpression, Action`1 bulkOperationFactory)
    DbContextExtensions.UpdateFromQuery[TEntity](IQueryable`1 query, Expression`1 updateExpression)
    ReceitasDAO.AtualizarReceitaElectronicaTaCoUidEntidadesCentralizadas(ReceitaEletronica receitaEletronica, List`1 entidades) line 114
    ReceitasDAOTest.TestAtualizarReceitaElectronicaTaCoUidEntidadesCentralizadas() line 267
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find out what caused this? I am getting the exact same error and the only Google result is this unanswered question. Are you using Table-Per-Hierarchy inheritance in your table? That is the only thing I can think of that is unusual about mine.

Comment: @TridentTrue (Love your nick, btw.) Yes, I did. The cause is that none of the various flavors of Z.EntityFramework.Extensions actually support this use case. Changing the way you build the query simply changes the error message you get. You can do mass updates for constants, and that's it. As for inheritance, I'm not using it at all.

Comment: Ah unfortunate, will have to find another way then. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

I have received such error when context had different object then the one I was passing to UpdateFromQuery.

For example for context `DbSet<A>` I accidentally put `new B()`

```
  context.A.
         Where(x => x.Id == id).
         UpdateFromQuery(x => new B
            {
                Example = exampleId
            });
```

Hope it helps!